# xcode 6 iOS launchScreen.xib cannot be localized

Tags: ios, localization, xcode6

I localized the launchScreen.xib as below:

/* Class = "IBUILabel"; text = "  Copyright (c) 2014年 Felix Morgan. All rights reserved."; ObjectID = "8ie-xW-0ye"; */
"8ie-xW-0ye.text" = "  Copyright (c) 2014年 Felix Morgan. All rights reserved.";

/* Class = "IBUILabel"; text = "Your Girlfriend"; ObjectID = "kId-c2-rCX"; */
"kId-c2-rCX.text" = "Your Girlfriend";

/* Class = "IBUILabel"; text = "  Copyright (c) 2014年 Felix Morgan. All rights reserved."; ObjectID = "8ie-xW-0ye"; */
"8ie-xW-0ye.text" = "  Copyright (c) 2014年 Felix Morgan. All rights reserved.";

/* Class = "IBUILabel"; text = "女 友"; ObjectID = "kId-c2-rCX"; */
"kId-c2-rCX.text" = "女  友";

but It's the English text all the time;
what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the same issue. Asked a few days ago - latest info from one user:

> I do not think LaunchScreen.xib is working with Internationalisation yet. The only thing I got working is preview in Xcode. Maybe Apple will fix this in near future. –  Peter Nov 9 at 11:55